What is pseudo inverse of x.T A x, where A is a positive definite symmetric matrix, and x is a column vector.
what is pseudo inverse of x.T A x, where A is a positive definite symmetric matrix, x is a column vector and x.T is the transpose of x. I am wondering whether it can be rewitten in terms of the inverse of A.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but $x^{T}Ax$ is a scalar, and since $A$ is positive definite, you also know that for any non-zero column vector $x$, it holds that $x^{T}Ax > 0$. So the inverse would just be $1/(x^{T}Ax)$ right?
